# Tags in 'tagged' section won't update after edit

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, tags, edits

I've noticed this bug on Stack Overflow but it may be a common issue on all Stack Exchange sites.

After editing question's tags 'tagged' section (seen in the right section) won't update after editing question's tags. Hitting F5 updates this info.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit question's tags.

Actual result:

1. Question tags below question text are updated.
2. Question tags in the section 'tagged' to the right of question are not updated.

Expected result:

1. Tags in both sections are updated.

Comment: Caching, the answer is always caching.

Comment: @psubsee2003 not in this case. Rare, but happens. It's only for inline editing though.

Comment: Going to guess this is [tag:status-bydesign]